# Is there a way to insert ng-if inside the ng-click in angular js

Tags: angularjs

For example i am having

```
ng-click="availability(avail);profileSections.experience.open = true;"
```

But now i wan't to send the second expression as an condition as

```
ng-click="availability(avail);error == true?'profileSections.experience.open = true': "";"
```

Can any one please suggest

Comment: Call a function in the controller that implements an if condition?

Comment: Will post an answer in a bit!

Comment: Please check the new answer

Comment: Yes that's what i have done before see  ng-click="addreferences();CheckError();" but now that return is not getting binded here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional statements directly in [ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/directive/ngClick) directive. here is an sample for ternary operator to use in ngClick...

```
ng-click="availability(avail);error === true?profileSections.experience.open = true: return"
```

Comment: That does work but I'd suggest to do what @Satej said for better readability.

Comment: If this code worked for you then upward it or mark "This answer is useful". Yes, you can use like that but if there is no more code accept this then you should use a function in controller, this is very good practice.


"HAPPY CODING"

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this answer after being asked by OP.
Here's what I would do to declutter my syntax in `ng-click`.I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but you should be able to understand a just of it.

Call a function upon button click, something like this

`<button ng-click="process();">Click Here</button>`

In the function, do the following

```
  $scope.process =function(){
         alert("clicked");
         //Do something like this
         /*
         First Call the function you want to analyze
         $scope.error-x=availability(avail)
         if($scope.error) This checks if the error is true
         profileSections.experience.open = true//Perform action if true
         else
         profileSections.experience.open = ''//Perform action if false
         */
       }
```

I wouldn't say there is a particular advantage to using this method, but it definitely is more readable.You can try your logic [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qdRZOIrm4mbNdKaPHlx8?p=preview)

Comment: that's what i was trying to do Its not returning ex ng-click="addreferences();CheckError();" ' $scope.CheckError = function (SRForm)
    {if ($scope.SRForm.$valid) {alert("true");
                return "profileSections.professionalexperience.open = true"
            }
    }'

Comment: where is the addreferences function?